# how can I show Progress Bar in my iPhone view while data is downloading from the server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my iPhone application, I am downloading data from the server, now I want to show a progress bar which will show the downloading status on the screen, I know how to add a progress bar in my screen but don't know how it'll show the status progress.

Comment: What do you use to download a file?

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD